# haar wavelet transform

Tags: image-processing, transformation, haar-wavelet

I have a function which will calculate haar transformation for an image. Now i am passing the pixel values of the image directly to the haar function for computation. Iam not getting the original image back in LL sub band. Please help me whats wrong. I am very sure the harr transform computation is correct. But I am not sure what values to pass. Please help

Comment: Which library are you using? Or is it your code?

Comment: What library/code are you using?  I can't see the Java part in your question yet

Comment: @Noofiz Its my own code.. I want to know what values to pass in for applying haar transform

Comment: @emecas  Sorry for adding the java tag.. the prob is not with java..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use **RGB image** , so you need to split it to **3 channels** and get the **Haar** for each channel(red, green , blue).

if the image is **Gray** one , so use it's pixel direct in Haar Function

Comment: I am using a grayscale image only. And i passed the values directly. But still i am not able to reproduce the original image

Comment: When i am getting haar for each color channel (i.e; red, blue and green) there is a possibility that it might go into out of range because of averaging. So it is giving me 'Out of color range error'. What should i do to avoid this

Comment: i think that you implemented this function , so i don't know exactly what you do , if you have time you can try this code (it' java) http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/haar-wavelet and the source code :http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/HaarFilter.java ,  if you read the code it will help you , and if you can post your code here you will get the help :)

Comment: I have used the same code.. but i am not normalizing the values. i dint understand what to give for fractional bits